# Strange loadNibNamed behaviour

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nsdocument, nsbundle

I have a document-based Cocoa app. During runtime, I load an additional nib from the bundle by invoking `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"inspectorNIB" owner:self]` (where `self` is the `NSDocument`).

Strangely enough, while loading the bundle succeeds, it invokes the `NSDocument`'s `awakeFromNib` method again, causing an unnecessary second initialisation. Is this expected behaviour? How can I suppress it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `-awakeFromNib` is called for each nib that's loaded if the object is referenced in the nib. If you want to avoid doing setup twice, you can set a `BOOL` instance variable and do a check:

```
if (!alreadyDidNibLoadStuff) {
    // do nib load stuff
    alreadyDidNibLoadStuff = YES;
}
```